# how to pivot a table in sql

Tags: sql, pivot

I created a table as follows:

```
create table stud(sname nvarchar(10), hr nvarchar(30),  dt int,att varchar(3))
```

And I inserted  values as  follows:

```
insert into stud values ('Abi',  '1',  '21/01/2013','a')
insert into stud values ('Abi',  '2',  '21/01/2013','p')


insert into stud values ('bala',  '1',  '21/01/2013','p')
insert into stud values ('bala',  '2',  '21/01/2013','a')


insert into stud values ('bala',  '1',  '22/01/2013','od')
insert into stud values ('bala',  '2',  '22/01/2013','ml')

insert into stud values ('Abi',  '1',  '22/01/2013','ml')
insert into stud values ('Abi',  '2',  '22/01/2013','od')
```

---

If select the table means means I got output as:

```
sname   hr   dt   att

abi      1    20/1/2013 a
abi      2    20/1/2013 p

bala      1    20/1/2013 p
bala      2    20/1/2013 a
```

---

But I want output as :

```
sname    h1    h2

abi      a      p
bala     p      a
```

How to pivot the table..

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... more advanced features are very much vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 1):

This type of transformation is known as a *pivot*.  I am assuming SQL Server as the database due to the usage of `nvarchar` in the create table code you provided.

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, then you can use the pivot function and the code will be:

```
select sname, [1] as h1, [2] as h2
from
(
  select sname, hr, att
  from stud
  where att in ('a', 'p')
) d
pivot
(
  max(att)
  for hr in ([1], [2])
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e551/5).

If you are not using SQL Server 2005+ or are on another data base that does not support pivot, then you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select sname,
  max(case when hr=1 then att end) as H1,
  max(case when hr=2 then att end) as H2
from stud
where att in ('a', 'p')
group by sname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e551/7)

Answer (score 0):

The response by Ray in [Sql Server 2008 Cross Tab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956908/sql-server-2008-cross-tab-query) should provide you with the details you need for a standards compliant DBMS.