# How to make multiple columns based on rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table names Attendance Master

```
id  ||name ||attn_hours || attn_date
---------------------------------------------
142 || abc || 2.00 || 2013-01-17 00:00:00.000
142 || abc || 3.00 || 2013-01-18 00:00:00.000
143 || pqr || 3.00 || 2013-01-17 00:00:00.000
143 || pqr || 2.00 || 2013-01-18 00:00:00.000
```

I want distinct names and attendance hours in multiple column with column names as attn_date like
following

```
id  ||name ||2013-01-17||2013-01-18
---------------------------------
142 || abc || 2.00 || 3.00
143 || pqr || 3.00 || 2.00
```

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have **you** tried so far?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any messy `<br/>` tags, either!

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: i prefer to create dynamic sql here.

Comment: i am using sql server 2008

Comment: Use the response in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956908/sql-server-2008-cross-tab-query for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  Id, name, [2013-01-17], [2013-01-18]
FROM Tbl
PIVOT
(
  MAX(attn_hours)
  FOR attn_date in ([2013-01-17], [2013-01-18])
) A
```

or this:

```
SELECT
  Id, 
  name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN attn_date = '2013-01-17' THEN attn_hours END) [2013-01-17],
  MAX(CASE WHEN attn_date = '2013-01-18' THEN attn_hours END) [2013-01-18]
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY Id, Name
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b335/3)**

Comment: 2nd one, without `PIVOT` worked for me in Google BigQuery. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pivot your data.  In sql server 2008 you can do this by following the guide @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

then you can understand why this works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f8a3/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @Dates VARCHAR(8000)
Declare @Month int=1

SELECT @Dates = COALESCE(@Dates + '], [', '') + cast(attn_date as varchar(20)) FROM 
(select distinct attn_date from tbl where month(attn_date)=@Month) as a


Set @Dates='['+@Dates+']'

--SELECT @Dates




Declare @query varchar(max)


Set @query=
'SELECT
Id, name, ' + @Dates + ' 
FROM Tbl
PIVOT
(
  MAX(attn_hours)
  FOR attn_date in (' + @Dates + ' )   
) A'

print @query

exec(@query)
```