# Get number of incident per product per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, grouping

We are using a ticket tracking system and I want to get out the information how many ticket were created for each product per month:

```
Product Jan 12  Feb 12
Product 1   130  99
Product 2   13  14
Product 3   7   9
Product 4       
Product 5   13  7
Product 6   22  31
Product 7       
Product 8   10  5
```

Database: MS SQL Server 2008
Table Name: incidentbase
Relevant Fields:
* Createdon (datetime)
* Productname (nvarchar)

I can get out the information but not in the format shown above with the following SQL:

```
Select (convert(varchar(7), CreatedOn, 102)) as 'month', Productname as Product,  COUNT(*) as number
from Incidentbase
where createdon >= '2011-01-01'
group by Productname, (convert(varchar(7), CreatedOn, 102))
ORDER BY (convert(varchar(7), i.CreatedOn, 102))
```

```
month   Product number
2011.01 Product1    1
2011.01 Product2    93
2011.01 Product3    20
2011.02 Product1    98
2011.02 Product2    23
2011.02 Product3    7
```

Any idea how to change the SQL to show the correct groupings?

Comment: You need a crosstab-style query - take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956908/sql-server-2008-cross-tab-query

Comment: Why not simple use your existing result (which is quite good) and iterate over it with the programing language you are using? Normaly a result is a 2 dim Array, containing x-direction: attributes, y-direction: elements and the VALUE in the respective junction. Your desired result would contain values(a certain month) in the x-axis, which would require an own *select column* per column. It can be done, but i don't think it's nice. (If you want tdo Display 10 Years, you Need 120 column definitions...)

Comment: What's your product table called? (You will need to outer join from it to include products that have had no sales recorded within the specified timeframe, such as Product 4 in the supplied example.)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can implement the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to transform data from rows in columns:

```
select productname,
  [2011.01], 
  [2011.02]
from
(
  select ProductName,
    (convert(varchar(7), CreatedOn, 102)) as 'month'
  from Incidentbase
  where createdon >= '2011-01-01'
) src
pivot
(
  count(month)
  for month in ([2011.01], [2011.02])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e91bf/1)

If you have an unknown number of dates that you want to transform into columns, then you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME((convert(varchar(7), CreatedOn, 102))) 
                    from Incidentbase
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ProductName,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                  select ProductName,
                    (convert(varchar(7), CreatedOn, 102)) as month
                  from Incidentbase
                  where createdon >= ''2011-01-01''
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(month)
                for month in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e91bf/3).

If you want to pass into the dynamic query the date, then you would use a slightly different version of the code:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @startdate datetime

set @startdate = '2011-01-01'

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME((convert(varchar(7), CreatedOn, 102))) 
                    from Incidentbase
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ProductName,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                  select ProductName,
                    (convert(varchar(7), CreatedOn, 102)) as month
                  from Incidentbase
                  where createdon >= '+convert(varchar(10), @startdate, 120)+'
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(month)
                for month in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e91bf/4)