# Setting up database structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out the best way to restructure my database as I didn't plan ahead and now I am a little stuck on this part :)

I have a Table called Campaigns and a Table called Data Types.

Each campaign is a unique record that holds about 10 fields of data.

The data types contains 3 fields - ID, Type, Description

When You create a campaign, you can select as many data types as you would like.

1, 2 or all 3 of them.

My concern / question is - How can I store what the user selected with the campaign record?

I need to be able to pull in the campaign details but also know which data types were selected.

How I originally had it set up was the data types were in 1 field, comma separated but learned is not ideal to do that.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Storing the data as XML ?

**UPDATE -**

Here is an example of the query I was trying to get to work (its probably way off).

```
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT *
                FROM   (SELECT  A.[campaignID] as campaignID,
                                A.[campaignTitle],
                                A.[campaignDesc],
                                A.[campaignType],
                                A.[campaignStatus],
                                A.[duration],
                                A.[whoCreated],
                                B.[campaignID],
                                B.[dataType],
                                 (SELECT *
                                  FROM   Tags_Campaign_Settings
                                  WHERE  campaignID = @campaignID) AS dataTypes
                        FROM     Tags_Campaigns AS A
                                 INNER JOIN
                                 Tags_Campaign_Settings AS B
                                 ON A.[campaignID] = B.[campaignID]
                        WHERE    A.[campaignID] = @campaignID
                       ) AS a
                FOR    XML PATH ('campaigns'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
                    END 
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a join table called Campain_DataType with campaignId and dataTypeId. Make sure they're foreign key constrained to the respective tables. When you query for campaign data, you can either create a separate query to get the data type information based on the campaignId, or you can do a left outer join to fetch campaigns and their data types together.

If you want to collapse the 3 data types into the same row, then give the following a shot. It's definitely on the hacky side, and it'll only work with a fixed number of data types. If you add another data type, you'll have to update this query to support it.

```
SELECT
  Campaign.ID,
  Campaign.foo,
  Campaign.bar,
  dataType1.hasDataType1,
  dataType2.hasDataType2,
  dataType3.hasDataType3
FROM
  Campaign
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  ( SELECT
      1 as hasDataType1,
      Campaign_DataType.campaignID
    FROM
      DataType
      INNER JOIN Campaign_DataType ON Campaign_DataType.dataTypeId = DataType.id
    WHERE
      DataType.Type = 'Type1'
  ) dataType1 ON dataType1.campaignID = Campaign.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  ( SELECT
      1 as hasDataType2,
      Campaign_DataType.campaignID
    FROM
      DataType
      INNER JOIN Campaign_DataType ON Campaign_DataType.dataTypeId = DataType.id
    WHERE
      DataType.Type = 'Type2'
  ) dataType2 ON dataType2.campaignID = Campaign.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  ( SELECT
      1 as hasDataType3,
      Campaign_DataType.campaignID
    FROM
      DataType
      INNER JOIN Campaign_DataType ON Campaign_DataType.dataTypeId = DataType.id
    WHERE
      DataType.Type = 'Type3'
  ) dataType3 ON dataType3.campaignID = Campaign.ID
```

The record you receive for each Campaign will have three fields: hasDataType1, hasDataType2, hasDataType3. These columns will be 1 for yes, NULL for no.

Comment: During my research I figured it would end up being something like this but when I tried it and did my join on campaignID, it gave me a duplicate set of data with the only difference being the dataType ID. I wasnt sure how to just get one record if possible with all IDs associated to it

Comment: Okay, I have something for you - standby.

Comment: Okay, I posted an example of what I tried to do based on what you had said but I think its way off

Comment: Give my update a shot. I only typed it here in browser, so I don't know if it's gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like what you want here is a crosstab query. Take a look at: 
[Sql Server 2008 Cross Tab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956908/sql-server-2008-cross-tab-query)