# return the count of row even if null sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I trying to do a sql query to get the count for shift for each user 
I used this query :

```
SELECT        
   COUNT(s.id) AS count, s.user_id
FROM            
   sarcuser AS u 
INNER JOIN
   sarcshiftpointuser AS s ON s.user_id = u.id 
INNER JOIN
   sarcalllevel AS l ON l.id = u.levelid 
INNER JOIN
   sarcshiftpointtable AS t ON t.shift_id = s.shift_id AND s.table_id = t.table_id
WHERE        
   (s.shift_id + '' LIKE '2') 
   AND (CAST(s.xdate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(N'2014-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST(N'2015-01-01' AS DATE)) 
   AND (u.gender + '' LIKE N'%') 
   AND (u.levelid + '' LIKE N'%') 
   AND (s.point_id + '' LIKE '2')
GROUP BY 
   s.user_id
ORDER BY 
   count
```

It works very well ... but there is a logic problem :

when the user didn't appear in the shift didn't return the count and I need it to return 0

For example :

```
           user1    user2
shift1      2         2
shift2      5         0
shift3      6         10
```

but actually the code returns :

```
           user1    user2
shift1      2         2
shift2      5         10
shift3      6
```

and that's wrong ... how to return the count even if it zero with this condition and this inner join ?

Sample for data in table :

```
sarcuser : 
    id  firstname   lastname   gender   levelid 
    52    samy       sammour    male       1
    62    ibrahim      jackob   male       1
    71    rebeca       janson   female     3

sarcalllevel :
    id    name
    1     field leader
    2       leader
    3       paramdic

sarcshiftpointtable : 
    id    shift_id    table_id    name_of_shift    point_id
    1        1           1              shift1         2
    2        2           1              shift2         2
    3        3           1              shift3         2
    4        1           2              shift1         7
    5        2           2              shift2         7
    6        3           2              shift3         7


sarcshiftpointuser : 

   id    point_id    shift_id    table_id    user_id    xdate  
    1       2            1          1           62        2014-01-05
    2       2            1          1           0         2014-01-05
    3       2            1          1           71        2014-01-05
    4       2            2          1           0         2014-01-05
    5       2            2          1           0         2014-01-05
    6       2            2          1           52        2014-01-05
    7       2            3          1           52        2014-01-05
    8       2            3          1           62        2014-01-05
    9       2            3          1           71        2014-01-05
    10      2            1          1           71        2014-01-06
    11      2            1          1           52        2014-01-06
    12      2            1          1           0         2014-01-06
    13      2            2          1           62        2014-01-06
    14      2            2          1           0         2014-01-06
    15      2            2          1           52        2014-01-06
    16      2            3          1           62        2014-01-06
    17      2            3          1           52        2014-01-06
    18      2            3          1           71        2014-01-06
```

if i apply this query 3 times by changing the shift should return :

```
          52    62    71       
shift1     1     2     2
shift2     2     1     0
shift3     2     2     2
```

in shift2 in sarcshiftpointuser the user 71 is not appear 
so when I do the code it will return just to field not three ? the count 0 is not returned

```
          52    62    71
shift2    2      1
```

to be more specific : 
I need to export this table into excel so when the 0 is not return it give me a wrong order and wrong value (logically )

Comment: Your sample data has users in columns.  Your query would put the users in rows.  And, there is no output of the shift.  Can you edit your question so the sample data and query are compatible?

Comment: maybe I miss that if you do this query 3 times by changing the shift_id give you that table 

but I need it where I search at shift_id = 2 (shift2)
it should return 
5  - 0 but it's only return 5 I need it to return the 0 also

Comment: Samy, will yo be able to give us sample data inside sarcuser , sarcshiftpointuser, sarcalllevel & sarcshiftpointtable tables. Then it will be easy for us to understand the real problem.

Comment: There are a number of other problems with your query, frankly.  It would take a **lot** more work for the query to collapse like you suggest.  As others have said, give us starting sample data, please.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a nested query using IFNULL

Take a look to this

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Something like,

IFNULL(user,0)

Comment: While `IFNULL()` (or its standard version, `COALESCE()`) _can_ provide results in the face of null, the statement here would need further modifications to take advantage of this.  At the moment, there's no row **at all** for the function to be called against.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring a crosstab query. you can use PIVOT to return your result set. Please refer below link.

[Sql Server 2008 Cross Tab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956908/sql-server-2008-cross-tab-query).

If you give few sample data for sarcuser , sarcshiftpointuser, sarcalllevel & sarcshiftpointtable tables, then we can give you a better answer.

Comment: Link-only answers are to be avoided - at minimum, you need to extract the portions you feel are relevant.  Yes, pivoting the data will give the results formatted in the indicated fashion; could you give a plausible modification to the original query?